# Create a Cursor and loop all users data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, cursor

I have a `Stored procedure` which gives me records like below.

[image: SC]

Now what I want is. I want to create a `CURSOR` for the SP which loops for every user and fetch the records.

Below is my SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT
            AS
            BEGIN

                      Select distinct
                          U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name UserName,
                    TH.*, 
                CASE 
                        WHEN TL.U_datetime < DATEADD(d, -5, GETDATE()) 
                        THEN M.Reporting_To
                            ELSE NULL 
                            END Reporting_1
                        from inward_doc_tracking_trl TL
                        INNER JOIN inward_doc_tracking_hdr TH
                            ON TH.mkey = TL.ref_mkey
                        INNER JOIN user_mst U
                            ON TH.User_Id = U.mkey
                        INNER JOIN emp_mst M
                            ON M.mkey = U.employee_mkey
                        where TL.NStatus_flag NOT IN (5,14)
                        and TL.U_datetime < DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE())
            END
GO
```

Kindly let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Dont use CURSORS. Very much redundant.   Please keep in mind this is for educational to show you how to use a WHILE LOOP and not to use CURSORS.  The SQL Format is incorrect and the SYNTAX can be very much improved.  But this shows how to LOOP only.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT
            AS
            BEGIN

            DECLARE @userName VARCHAR(512)

             CREATE TABLE #ReportData
            (
               UserName VARCHAR(128),
               MKey VARCHAR(64),
              ...................
            )

                      Select distinct
                          U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name UserName,
                    TH.*, 
                CASE 
                        WHEN TL.U_datetime < DATEADD(d, -5, GETDATE()) 
                        THEN M.Reporting_To
                            ELSE NULL 
                            END Reporting_1
                        INTO #data
                        from inward_doc_tracking_trl TL
                        INNER JOIN inward_doc_tracking_hdr TH
                            ON TH.mkey = TL.ref_mkey
                        INNER JOIN user_mst U
                            ON TH.User_Id = U.mkey
                        INNER JOIN emp_mst M
                            ON M.mkey = U.employee_mkey
                        where TL.NStatus_flag NOT IN (5,14)
                        and TL.U_datetime < DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE())


             WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #data) > 0
             BEGIN
                    SELECT TOP 1 @userName = UserName
                    FROM #data

                    INSERT INTO #ReportData
                    SELECT *
                    FROM #Data
                    WHERE UserName = @userName


                    DELETE #data
                    WHERE UserName = @userName
             END

                 SELECT * 
                 FROM #ReportData

                 DROP TABLE #ReportData
                 DROP TABLE #Data
            END
GO
```

Comment: what does `WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #data) > 0` do ? I just want to select and show the data in a loop.So, I need to use cursor for this

Comment: This is a LOOP. You dont need a Cursor.

Comment: so what does `Do your changes here` do. I dont want any operation, just select the statement

Comment: I changed the script

Comment: Question. Do you want to call the Stored Procedure and loop through the records?

Comment: yes, this is working. can I show that in a single table. ?? I mean in a temp table. Now it is showing different rows for different users

Comment: I changed the script. So now it will display all the results, instead of single rows.

Comment: Getting error as `There is already an object named '#ReportData' in the database.`

Comment: No wait. I will fix it

Comment: getting error as `There is already an object named '#ReportData' in the database.`

Comment: Ok, You have to create another temp table, but explicitly add the columns.  And then in the loop you add to the #ReportData temp table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115830/discussion-between-n-k-and-mvisser).

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to get the resultset from another Stored Procedure.

```
           ALTER PROCEDURE GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT
            AS
            BEGIN

            DECLARE @userName VARCHAR(512)


            CREATE TABLE #Data
            (
                UserName VARCHAR(128),
                MKey VARCHAR(64),
                ...................
            )



             INSERT INTO #Data
             EXEC StoredProcedureName


             WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #data) > 0
             BEGIN
                    SELECT TOP 1 @userName = UserName
                    FROM #data


                    SELECT *
                    FROM #Data
                    WHERE UserName = @userName

                    SELECT @userName

                    DELETE #data
                    WHERE UserName = @userName
             END

             DROP TABLE #Data

            END
GO
```